# Using @query on CrudRepository(Spring data jdbc) with table join

Tags: join, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying spring data jdbc with @query and I met a question: If I have a query that joins 2
tables like this:

```
@Query("select a.*, b.* from master a, detail b where b.master_id=a.id and a.id=:id")
```

How do I get the response?
The official [Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) didn't give any hint on it. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options:

**Use the default `RowMapper`**

Use as the return type a class (or a collection of that class) that has properties for all the fields you are selecting.
This will return a single element for each row.

Since you are referring to the two tables as `master` and `detail` you probably don't want that in this case.

**Use a custom `RowMapper`**

The [`@Query` annotation allows you to specify your own `rowMapperClass`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/query/Query.html#rowMapperClass--) which will get instantiated and passed to a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` together with your query.

Again this will result in on result element per row selected and therefore probably isn't what you want.

**Use a custom `ResultSetExtractor`**

[This can be again specified in the `@Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/query/Query.html#resultSetExtractorClass--).
And allows you to construct the result in an arbitrary way.
See the documentation for `ResultSetExtractor` for more details.

Remark: If you are using a `ResultSetExtractor` to create a single `Master` with multiple `Detail` instances from multiple rows of your query result make sure to add an `ORDER BY master.id`. Otherwise the order of rows is likely as desired but actually not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the last method.